# The Invantive Control for Excel add-in has disappeared from the ribbon in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

Usually when I start up Microsoft Excel, the Invantive Control add-in loads automatically.

But it has now disappeared from the ribbon. How can I make the Invantive Control add-in active again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Invantive Control add-in is disabled within Microsoft Excel, you can easily enable it again following these steps:

Step 1: Go to 'File' and then 'Options'

[image: Go to File > Options]

Step 2: Click on "Add-Ins" in the menu on the left

[image: Click on "Add-Ins"]

Step 3: Choose "COM Add-ins" from the dropdown at the bottom next to "Manage:"

[image: Choose "COM Add-ins" from the dropdown]

Step 4: Enable the 'Invantive Control for Excel' add-in by clicking the checkbox

[image]

Now press OK, Invantive Control will be enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

When the add-in does not appears with COM add-ins, it might be fully disabled. Please check Disabled items then in the drop down.

[image: Disable items for invantive control]